Draggable image element is translucent when dragging
I'm making a javascript implementation of chess. I currently have images for the pieces stored in td elements in a table. With event listeners I've made it so they can drag and drop between squares, but the image attached to the cursor is translucent and has a plus with a box symbol underneath it. I've attempted using setDragImage, but it provides the same issue. Is there anyway to make it have opacity 1 and remove the symbol? Sorry if this is has already been answered, I tried searching but couldnt find a good solution. Ask if any more information would be helpful and thankyou in advance.
